# Simplified statement for string concatenation

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to concatenate some attributes from the xml below:

```
set @data = N'<properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>first</name>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>second</name>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>third</name>
                    </property>
                </properties>'
```

If the result I want to extract is: **first,second,third**, such a simple statement can be used:

```
declare @result nvarchar(max)
select @result = coalesce(@result + ',', '') + x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') 
from @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') as xtbl(x)
```

If the result I want to extract is: **first=#.first,second=#.second,third=#.third**, my solution looks like below:

```
declare mycursor cursor fast_forward
for select
    x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)')
from
    @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') AS xtbl(x)

declare @name nvarchar(50), @result nvarchar(max) = N'$name$=#.$name2$'

open mycursor
fetch next from mycursor into @name
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin               
    set @result= replace(@result, N'$name$', @name)
    set @result = replace(@result, N'$name2$', @name + N',$name$=#.$name2$')
    fetch next from mycursor into @name
end
close mycursor;
deallocate mycursor;

set @result = replace(@result, N',$name$=#.$name2$', '')
```

How to do this without the usage of any loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
declare @result nvarchar(max)=''
select @result = @result + x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') 
                         + '=#.' 
                         + x.value(N'(name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') 
                         + ','
from @data.nodes(N'/properties/property') as xtbl(X)   
select @result = left(@result, LEN(@result)-1)
print @result
```